# Firefox svg symbol transform

Tags: css, firefox, svg, symbols

I am having unexpected behaviour in Firefox while using SVG symbols and position: absolute with transform: translate();

This only seems to be happening in Firefox, not IE or Chrome. I am also reasonably sure I wasn't having this issue previously, so perhaps is a new issue/bug? Currently using 43.0.4 (Windows) and have also tested in 44.0.2 (Linux).

In [this Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/AAvjxGtwznA1PWOVOOr7?p=preview) I would expect the map pointer, circle and square all to be positioned centrally within the bounding box. However, in Firefox the map pointer is not positioned correctly. The map pointer is an SVG symbol.

**update:** the issue seems to present itself only if the SVG is positioned using svg{} as the CSS selector. It works as expected if it is styled via the .icon{} selector.

CODE:

```css
#svg-sprite{
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.rect{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #f00;
}

svg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  fill: #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.circle{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #0f0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.square{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  fill: #0f0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <svg id="svg-sprite">
      <symbol viewBox="0 0 42 60" id="map_pointer"><title>map_pointer</title><path d="M21 .254C9.52.254.178 9.594.178 21.076c0 11.153 19.208 37.167 20.026 38.27.187.25.483.4.796.4.313 0 .61-.15.796-.4.818-1.103 20.026-27.117 20.026-38.27C41.822 9.596 32.482.254 21 .254zM21 30c-4.92 0-8.924-4.003-8.924-8.924 0-4.92 4.003-8.923 8.924-8.923 4.92 0 8.924 4.002 8.924 8.923C29.924 25.996 25.92 30 21 30z"/></symbol>
    </svg>
    
    <p>SVG icon should be positioned in centre of rectangle. In Firefox this is not the case</p>
    
    <div class="rect">
      <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#map_pointer" /></svg>
      
      <div class="circle"></div>
      
      <svg class="square" width="200" height="200">
        <rect width="200" height="200" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here it looks fine in firefox also. Using latest version of firefox.

Comment: It seems, if I style via svg{} rather than .icon{} it is broken in firefox, but no other browsers. I had updated the plunker to a class for neatness and that's why it didn't appear for @ketan

Comment: I see perfect the snippet and the plunker in firefox 44.0.2 in Mac. It doesn't targets with `.icon` so I don't know why you see it wrong

Comment: @PaulThomasGC You right. If we target css to `svg` instead of `.icon` then it looks wrong in firefox.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude - do you know what version of FF you are running? Have just tried in 44.0.2 on Mac and it is not working correctly there.

Comment: As I said, firefox 44.0.2. I think that the good display is the green circle in the absolute center of the red box. It's true? Well, this is that I see in snippet and plunker.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude - there should also be a map pointer in the centre, which if displaying incorrectly as I suspect it is (as you did not mention it) will be incorrectly placed offset to the top left.

Comment: I don't know what is a "map pointer" but yes, I don't see it. I see a green circle with a little shape in the top-left of itself, and all is center in the red box :(

Comment: For anyone following this, I have raised it as a bug with Mozilla at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1248369

Comment: @PaulThomasGC Not a bug in Firefox, a bug in Chrome has led to you misunderstanding how transform-origin and transform-box work.

Comment: @RobertLongson - I have seen your comment on BugZilla also. Please could you explain further for me. As it is not clear to me why it would work as expected (Chrome/IE bug or otherwise) when using a class selector rather than the element selector. I'm also not sure as to the relevance of transform-origin as to my understanding, that wouldn't be relevant here.

Comment: When you write 50% what thing is it 50% of? The transform-box property defines that. If I run a Firefox nightly and add transform-box: fill-box; to the CSS, Firefox displays similar to Chrome.

Comment: @RobertLongson so why does this change between class (.icon{}) and element (svg{})? Also, the inline svg (the square) seems to behave as expected regardless of element/class selector and altering the transform-box property has no effect? If I'm incorrect in stating that it is a bug, I would at least like to fully understand why.

Comment: The rect is the same size as the svg that contains it so the fill-box of the rect is the same as the view-box of the rect. Please read up on the meaning of the CSS transform-box property.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'll happily read further into transform-box. However, one last request before I sign off for this evening at least - why does the behaviour change between class and element selector? ie. applying transform to .icon{} works as I would expect (or at least as IE/Chrome behave) but applying transform to svg{} does not.

Answer (score 2):

I've just removed the css **transform** from the **svg** then arrange the **top** and **left**. It's working in firefox too. I think it may the answer you are expecting.

```css
#svg-sprite{
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.rect{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #f00;
}

svg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  fill: #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.circle{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #0f0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.square{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  fill: #0f0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <svg id="svg-sprite">
      <symbol viewBox="0 0 42 60" id="map_pointer"><title>map_pointer</title><path d="M21 .254C9.52.254.178 9.594.178 21.076c0 11.153 19.208 37.167 20.026 38.27.187.25.483.4.796.4.313 0 .61-.15.796-.4.818-1.103 20.026-27.117 20.026-38.27C41.822 9.596 32.482.254 21 .254zM21 30c-4.92 0-8.924-4.003-8.924-8.924 0-4.92 4.003-8.923 8.924-8.923 4.92 0 8.924 4.002 8.924 8.923C29.924 25.996 25.92 30 21 30z"/></symbol>
    </svg>
    
    <p>SVG icon should be positioned in centre of rectangle. In Firefox this is not the case</p>
    
    <div class="rect">
      <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#map_pointer" /></svg>
      
      <div class="circle"></div>
      
      <svg class="square" width="200" height="200">
        <rect width="200" height="200" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

### Heading

Here I have made some changes to your code and this works fine some css3 properties needs vendor specific property values like transform needs `-moz-transform` to work in mozilla `-o-transform` to work in opera `-webkit-transform` to work with safari and chrome and in some critical case you may have to add base statement while using css3 propeties because some of css3 properties doesnt work with IE 8 or below

```css
#svg-sprite{
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.rect{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #f00;
}

svg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0% , 0% );
    -moz-transform: translate(0% , 0% );
    -ms-transform: translate(0% , 0% );
    -o-transform: translate(0% , 0% );
   transform: translate(0% , 0%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  fill: #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.circle{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
   
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #0f0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.square{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  fill: #0f0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <svg id="svg-sprite">
      <symbol viewBox="0 0 42 60" id="map_pointer"><title>map_pointer</title><path d="M21 .254C9.52.254.178 9.594.178 21.076c0 11.153 19.208 37.167 20.026 38.27.187.25.483.4.796.4.313 0 .61-.15.796-.4.818-1.103 20.026-27.117 20.026-38.27C41.822 9.596 32.482.254 21 .254zM21 30c-4.92 0-8.924-4.003-8.924-8.924 0-4.92 4.003-8.923 8.924-8.923 4.92 0 8.924 4.002 8.924 8.923C29.924 25.996 25.92 30 21 30z"/></symbol>
    </svg>
    
    <p>SVG icon should be positioned in centre of rectangle. In Firefox this is not the case</p>
    
    <div class="rect">
      <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#map_pointer" /></svg>
      
      <div class="circle"></div>
      
      <svg class="square" width="200" height="200">
        <rect width="200" height="200" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

and in case in future if u find any some similar difficulties use inspect element and check whether the desired css class is applied for the element or not and most of the cases inspect element will give you the proper error message too